# How do you use queries with a dataset in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have made a dataset in a Visual Studio project. It has the default queries, that being Fill and GetData, but I will be adding more in the future

I cannot find any resource or information regarding how to use these queries in my code. I have configured the functions with the default values, and I have searched up any relevant search term. However, I still have not found any way to cajole these queries into being useable in my code

How do I use these dataset queries?

Comment: [Fill datasets by using TableAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/fill-datasets-by-using-tableadapters?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new query to a table adapter in the `DataSet` designer, you are prompted to provide the method names by which the query will be invoked. The default methods are `Fill`, which populates an existing `DataTable`, and `GetData`, which returns a new `DataTable`. When prompted, the names used are `FillBy` and `GetDataBy` and the idea is that you add whatever column(s) you are filtering by. For instance, if you add the query *"SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn = ?"* then you should provide the method names `FillBySomeColumn` and `GetDataBySomeColumn`. You would then, for example, call `FillBySomeColumn` instead of `Fill` and provide the filter value as an argument, e.g. instead of this:

```vb
exampleTableAdapter.Fill(exampleDataSet.SomeTable)
```

you would use this:

```vb
exampleTableAdapter.FillBySomeColumn(exampleDataSet.SomeTable, someValue)
```

Comment: It's saying that non-shared members need an object reference when I use the Fill query

Comment: @IchthysKing, then create one. You don't use the class; you use an instance of the class.

Comment: How do I make an object reference? I can't find anything or work out how to do it

Comment: @That's programming basics and nothing to do with this question specifically. If you don't know how to create objects in VB by now then stop what you're doing and read a beginners tutorial to learn the basics before you go any further. If you do know how to create objects, which I suspect you do and have already multiple times but, for some reason, are thinking that this should be different for some reason. It's not.

Comment: I don't know what sort of objects I need, or how to assign the table to them. And I have searched everywhere to find answers but there is nothing there

Comment: @IchthysKing, you do know what sort of object you need. You need an instance of the table adapter that corresponds to the `DataTable` you want to populate. The clue is that the names are the same except the adapter has "Adapter" on the end. You don't "assign" the table to them. You call the appropriate method and pass the appropriate table as an argument, exactly as I have demonstrated. Again, you seem not to understand the absolute basics so stop what you're doing and learn the fundamentals first. If you ask how to adda query to a table adapter, how to create an object is assumed knowledge.